# React-Native-Web error: rnw_blogpost.bundle.js:1414 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBatchingLegacy')

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

Adding `react-native-web` package to existing RN app (made with `react-native init`).  Following the setup from this site:

https://arry.medium.com/how-to-add-react-native-web-to-an-existing-react-native-project-eb98c952c12f

The project compiles successfully, but in the browser I get a blank white screen and an error that loops:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBatchingLegacy')
```

I can't find anything about this error, I have traced the relevant files and am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same error message while running test after upgrading *react-test-renderer* package from v17 to v18. So in my case, I had to downgrade *react-test-renderer* from v18 to v17 **or** upgrading *react* from v17 to v18 also worked to correct this error.

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/17865), isBatchingLegacy is a deprecated function in *react-test-renderer*.

So, I'm not sure about it, because I don't know which packages do you have in your existing RN app, but you can maybe check the packages version you have in order to see if the error could come from here.

Comment: thanks for the response!  in my app i am using:
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",

i upgraded to react v18 and its working now!  thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same problem. Make sure all React dependencies are on the same version in your `package.json`.

```
"react": "~18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, I just spent 4 hours trying to figure out why I got the same error as you with `react-native-testing-library`

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react-native";
```

I **downgraded the types** on my `package.json`

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.1.0",
  "jest": "26",

  ...

  --"@types/react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
  ++"@types/react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
}
```

It's working now